# Unresolved compilation problems: EnhancedForStatementHeaderInit expected after this token

Tags: java

I am using JDK 1.8 and got an error like:

> Unresolved compilation problems: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced
>   construct(s) Syntax error on token ":", EnhancedForStatementHeaderInit
>   expected after this token

My class is:

```
@Service
public class TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;


    public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
        //return topics;
        List<Topic> top = new ArrayList<Topic>();
        topicRepository.findAll()
            .forEach(top::add);

        return topics;
    }
}
```

When I use lambda expressions in line no. 8:

```
topicRepository.findAll()
    .forEach(top::add);
```

Then I got the error.

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: What does `topicRepository.findAll()` return?

Comment: Are you aware that this code does nothing else than `new ArrayList<Topic>(topicRepository.findAll())` ? Using stream operation like one in your example does not make much sense imho.

Comment: Have you considered fixing your syntax errors *before* you try to run your code?

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling with `-source 1.7`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi All thanks for helping me to solve this issue and asking me some helping questions.

I am using java 1.8 and epclise kepler, and eclipse kepler not suport the java 1.8 compiler. 
So I am enable the Kepler java 1.8 compiler suport using following link:-

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

My problem is solved.

Again Thanks to all of you.